# Regex for validating decimal values

Tags: c#, regex, winforms, validation, expression

I am now using this regex,

`Regex rg = new Regex(@"\d{1,16}\.?|\d{0,16}\.\d{1,3}");`

to validate the decimal values entered into a Textbox. It works fine. But it allows a user to enter decimal values together with non-numeric characters like `2.a` or `2\`.

I believe that wrong portion is here `\.?`. I have used `?` so it accepts alphabetical values?
I have tried something like `\.[0-9]?` but it's not working.

Below are valid and invalid values:

- 1 --valid from 0 - 9
- 11 --valid
- 11.1 --valid
- 11.11 --valid
- 11.1111 -- valid until 4 decimal places
- 1a --invalid
- 1\ --invalid
- 1.1a --invalid
- a --invalid

*There might be duplicate questions on SO.* But valid regex tokens vary by implementation. That's why I asked a new question here. Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: is it possible for you to add the requirenemts you have for matching in plain text ? like this: digits left to decimal can be max 16 digits, etc

Comment: your question isn't clear.  You say it doesn't match '2.a' or '2\', then you list below that that it shouldn't match those values.  What do you want to match?  If this isn't the question, please tell us exactly what is wrong with expectations vs. actual results.

Comment: @ps2goat I have edited my question. It shouldn't accept alphabetical values in decimal. My expectation is I want to match numeric and dots only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use that regex:

```
^\d{1,16}(\.\d{1,4})?$
```

It will validate first between 1 and 16 digits an optional dot and 1 to 4 digits.

If you want to always have dot, you should use:

```
^\d{1,16}((\.\d{1,4})|(\.))?$
```

Comment: Input: `1.a`
`Regex rg = new Regex(@"\d{1,16}\.{0,1}\d{0,4}");` `myFlag = rg.IsMatch(inputStringToCheck);` I used your regex but it still match and returns `true`

Comment: I updated my answer as my first one wasn't completely correct.

Comment: Thanks. Now it works but it doesn't match `11.` , if I enter no digits after dot.

Comment: Because it's not a valid number?

Comment: That's why I added this \d{1,16}\.?| using `OR` operator in my code. Then, it matches alphabets again.

Comment: If you want to use, you can use: `^\d{1,16}((\.\d{1,4})|(\.))?$`

Comment: @Jowie, you need the ^ to indicate matching the start of the string and $ to indicate the end of the string.  With your original regex, you are matching the `2.` of `2.a`.  Unless you specify a start and end in your regex, the match can happen anywhere in the string value, which is why non-numeric characters were allowed after the decimal point.

Comment: @Szymon I make some changes to my program and how can I allow negative values in this regex, `^\d{1,16}((\.\d{1,4})|(\.))?$` you provided last time? Once again, thanks for your help.

Comment: @Szymon I tried doing something like these, `(\+|-)?`, `/^-?`, `^-?` but not working.

Comment: I'll check that in an hour or two.

Comment: That should be enough `^\-?\d{1,16}((\.\d{1,4})|(\.))?$`

Answer (score 1):

The regex

```
^\d{1,16}(\.\d{1,4})?$
```

works fine, if you want to recognize if only on point you can add

```
^(\d{1,16})|(\d{1,16}\.{1}\d{0,4})|(\d{1,16}\.{1})$
```

It's not as elegant as the other but works in the scenarios you posted.